# 401 - Unauthorized Error while accessing Graph API for MS Teams beta version

Tags: unauthorized

I'm trying to access message of Particular group from MS Teams using Graph API.

I'm using the following URL to get MS Teams messages(Using Beta Version).

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{group-id-for-teams}/channels/{channel-id}/messages

I am passing the correct token generated using below URL.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenent Id}/oauth2/v2.0/token

I'm facing 401 - Unauthorised error while accessing message when I apply it my JavaScript Code.

The API works fine when I am using the same with Graph Explorer.

I just want one clarity here, The Beta Version API not supported in Production(actual JavaScript Code) via Post/Get Method?

I also tries, some released API, with access token, it is working perfectly.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find an answer to this?